# Custom redirect URI for azure ad b2c native mobile app not working

Tags: azure, authentication, uwp, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have completed all steps properly according to the following sample.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-uwp

I have completed all optional steps as well, but when I test **Run Now** my **SignUpSignIn** Policy through azure portal, it keeps loading for a while and then just displays blank white page. I am pretty confident I have configured everything properly my only doubt is the **Custom Redirect URI** which I have set as following :

**com.onmicrosoft.fluensoft.fluennative://redirect/path**

> fluensoft is my tenant name
>
> fluennative is my native app name

in case of web app/ web api there are clear instructions that redirect uri is an http call, but in case of native custom redirect uri it is very confusing.

Comment: Have you opened developer tools and checked if there are any errors in the console or the network trace?

Comment: The redirect URL looks find and shouldn't be a problem when running "Run Now"

Comment: strangely it is working fine now without any problem, I guess it was a network problem yesterday. thanks anyways :)

Comment: Ah, good to hear. Can you add that as an answer and flag the questions as answered please?

Comment: done :)            ............

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

It was actually a network problem for that specific attempt when I tried the demo, I tried it again the next day and now it works as expected, If you are having the same problem then check your network in developer tools, also check the console just in case.

Comment: Check for what?